# Removing Controller and Action in Query String Format in Url in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on Asp.net MVC 4 with Razor. The urls of my projects are like

localhost:port/category1

localhost:port/category2 etc while my controller is home and action is MyCustomAction

I am using Paging on Category1 page with ul li and anchor tag  with `href="javascript:ShowPage(pagenmbr)`"

And Code of ShowPage function is `$('#currentpage').val(pagenmbr); $('#myform').submit();`

where currentpage is hidden field on my cshtml page

My form is

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("home","MyCustomAction",FormMethod.Post,new { @id="myform"})
```

and as i pressed any link for any page functionality is working properly

but in that case my url becomes

> localhost:port/category1?controller=home&action=MyCustomeAction

while I don't want this url pattern url should be

> localhost:port/category1

Am I doing something in a wrong way, please help me..... 
please help me out

Comment: "but in that case my url becomes" ...  what do you mean , when is this case??

Comment: (I just wrote it) not only in this case but in all cases..... when i post my form my url showing action and controller name in query string format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, there's something wrong in your routing. Try posting the code from your Route registering class.

Also for the below line:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("home","MyCustomAction",FormMethod.Post,new { @id="myform"})
```

Try switching this to:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
```

Doing this, will force the form to always submit to the current Url.

And you can't use the HtmlHelper to generate this as you need to specify the htmlAttributes which can only be passed after the actionName and the controllerName.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in my routing i had checked it twice thrice, in my routing i just checked first level after domain and checks if category exist and defines controller to home and action to MyCustome Action that's it, and if routing would wrong how the get request is giving desired result as `localhost:1111/category1`

Comment: Well Ganesh is right. You should switch to HTML markup.

Comment: Thanks... I used Html Form tag and got the desired result... but MVC form is also renders in Html form then how the result is diffrent.... can anyone explain .....